# Trying to get the function to return the arr with the pushed data in it, but for some reason its not returning it there

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Here I have required the sql in my main index file
seeded the database and checked that the sql query returns

```
// require sql connection from main index
const connection = require('./index');


async function tow() {
    let arr = []; 

    let one  = await connection.query("Select name FROM department", (err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log(res);
        console.log('1'arr);
        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            // pushing to the array here 
            arr.push(res[i].name);
        }
        console.log('2',arr);

    });
    console.log('3',arr);
    return one;

}

// I want this function to return array with the pushed elements 
tow();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return arr. Also you are mixing the promise style with the callback style of async, you can do either one, but not a mix. Try something like this.

If connection.query returns a promise:

```
async function tow() {
  let arr = []; 
  let one  = await connection.query("Select name FROM department").then(res => {
    // console.log(res);
    console.log('1', arr);
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        // pushing to the array here 
        arr.push(res[i].name);
    }
    console.log('2',arr);
    return arr; // need to return arr

},
err => console.error(err));
console.log('3',arr);
return one;  
}

tow().then(res => console.log('result', res));
```

In your case, where `connection.query` expects a callback function, you can convert the callback to a promise like this.

```
function tow() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let arr = []; 
    connection.query("Select name FROM department", (err, res) => {
      if (err) reject();
      // console.log(res);
      console.log('1', arr);
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          // pushing to the array here 
          arr.push(res[i].name);
      }
      console.log('2',arr);
      resolve(arr);
    });
  })
}

// I want this function to return array with the pushed elements 
tow().then(res => console.log('result', res));
```

Here's a codeSandbox

[image: Edit optimistic-volhard-hdwqt]

Comment: That's an unrelated problem.

Comment: my bad wrong error this one
TypeError: connection.query(...).then is not a function

Comment: ah, ok, so it is not returning a promise, but is expecting a callback function, so you won't be using async await. I can update my answer for that.

Comment: I updated my answer and the CodeSandbox example. Since I don't have the real `connection.query()` function, the example uses a mock function that returns after 2 seconds.

Comment: Others have done a better job explaining that than I can, maybe one of these will help you. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) or [https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies).

It basically is giving the JavaScript execution cycle a callback function and promises to call it in the future, and the function you pass into `.then()` are what gets executed when the reply comes back.

Comment: why do we need the promise to return it though? @EvanMorrison

Comment: In the original code, async/await doesn't help because `connection.query` doesn't return a promise, it doesn't return anything in fact (technically it returns undefined), so `one` will always remain undefined. Instead, when the response is ready `connection.query`  executes the callback function you gave it `(err, res) => {...`.  And `arr` will be stuck inside the callback function because there's no connection between it and `tow()`. Having `tow()` return a promise is a way to make a bridge from inside the callback function to the outside world through `resolve` and `.then()`.